# Macro for creating multiple charts not showing correct values for axes based on arrays

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to creating macros in VBA and have attempted to write one to make several charts. After researching and spending most of the day putting together what I have so far, the macro will make the amount of specified charts in the "For" loop, but the axes are not correct. The x axis is supposed to have the lowest and highest numbers in the starting range I use to create 'duplicatesArr' array as the bounds, while the y axis is intended to count each duplicate value in duplicatesArr ranging from 0 to (number of cells in specified range/2)

```
Sub CreateClusteredColumn()

Dim startCell As Range
Dim cellCount As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim cht As Object
Dim uniqArt As Variant
Dim duplicatesArr As Variant
Dim xAxis As Series
Dim yAxis As Series


For counter = 1 To 3

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2
    cht.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

    Set startCell = ActiveSheet.Range("F1").Offset(counter - 1, 0)
    Range(startCell, startCell.End(xlToRight)).Select
    cellCount = Selection.Cells.Count

    If cellCount < 30 Then 'not enough data to make a chart
        GoTo endLoop
        End If

    Dim perIssue() As Variant
    ReDim perIssue(0 To cellCount / 2)

    ySlice = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(perIssue, 0, 0))

    Set yAxis = cht.SeriesCollection(1)
    yAxis.Values = ySlice

    duplicatesArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(startCell, startCell.End(xlToRight))))
    uniqArt = RemoveDupes(duplicatesArr)

    Set xAxis = cht.SeriesCollection(1)
    xAxis.XValues = uniqArt

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Cut

    Sheets("GroupCharts").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Sheets("ArticleGroups").Select

endLoop:
Next counter

End Sub

Function RemoveDupes(InputArray) As Variant
    Dim dic As Object
    Dim Key As Variant
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each Key In InputArray
        dic(Key) = 0
    Next
    RemoveDupes = dic.keys
End Function
```

I am sure there are some obvious mistakes that my inexperienced eye has missed, but for me to spot them/research about them could take many hours, and I was hoping I may get some sort of direction on here to help. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqisp.png) is a link to the charts I am getting from running the macro. They were originally stacked on top of one another, even though I am trying to have them cut and pasted in the next sheet over, which is another less important issue. The main thing I need help on is understanding why the axes aren't turning out right. I would greatly appreciate any advice!

Edit: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e40i9.png) is an example of the data I am using. Without using a macro I have to make a pivot chart from a column to make a graph, but in the macro it takes data from the horizontal range. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by4iX.png) is a sample of a graph, but I would want the actual one to have Min. of 48 and Max. of 63 for this data set, and be distributed like a date axis.

Comment: Could you give a sample data and sample chart?

Comment: I just added it. Thanks for commenting.